# powershell how to join special folder with file

Tags: powershell

I tried :

```
Join-Path [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") "\test\test.txt"
```

but got error Join-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Comment: `Join-Path $([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) "\test\test.txt"`

Comment: What Olaf said, except you don't even need the `$`, so just `Join-Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) "\test\test.txt"` works. You just need to put parenthesis around it so PowerShell knows to evaluate that first, and then do the `Join-Path` part.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks but why do I need to use ( ) ? Why PowerShell doesn't know how to evaluate that first

Comment: It doesn't know to evaluate that first because there is nothing telling it to evaluate that first, that is why you have to use the ( ).

Comment: This is because PowerShell has two distinct parsing modes.  When it sees a command like `Join-Path`, it enters _argument mode_, which is very limited but simplifies easy tasks, e. g. passing unquoted string literals. For more complex arguments, you need to force it into _expression mode_, by using parentheses.